# How to initialize a database table with data using sequelize (and possibly, sequelize-fictures)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a data schema like this:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var LeadSource = sequelize.define('LeadSource', {
    source_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,      
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    source_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  });

  return LeadSource;
};
```

I want to populate the LeadSource table with the following data:

```
source_id    source_name
1            foo-source
2            foobar-source
3            foofoobar-source
```

How do I do this, so that the table is initialised *ONCE* (when it is first created)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you not check their github repo, it is quite clearly stated there.

> link: https://github.com/domasx2/sequelize-fixtures

No, you have to explicitly call a function to send the required test data to the db. It doesn't just go after you migrate the model but you may try this.

 Let's say models contain some user.js file, and your test data is in import.yaml having username, passwords etc.

 Then the code to seed in the db would be:

```
require('./models').sequelize.sync()
    .then(return require('sequelize-fixtures')
        .loadFile('import.yaml'), require('./models'))
```

and you can execute it after migrating using the scripts

```
scripts: {
    "migrate": "npx sequelize-cli db:migrate",
    "load-test-data": `node -e "require('./models').sequelize.sync().then(return require('sequelize-fixtures').loadFile('import.yaml'), require('./models'))"`,
    "migrate-db": "npm run migrate && npm run load-test-data"
}
```

Finally

```
npm run migrate-db
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It is not clear from the sequelize-fixtures docs - how to ensure that the fixtures are loaded **ONCE**. I want to ensure that the data is imported **ONCE** when the table is first created - but the docs don't state whether the code is to be placed in a model definition file - and if so, which section of the model definition file the code is to be placed.